# How to open help page in new window?

Tags: vim

How can I open `:help index` in new window explicitly choosing vertical or horizontal? For example, something like this:

```
:help index | vs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:vert[ical]`:

```
:vert help vertical
```